# Memory (RAM) issues using intersect from raster package

Tags: r, r-raster, r-sp, r-sf

I have trouble getting the intersection between two large SpatialPolygonsDataFrame on R. My polygons data represent buildings and administrative boundaries, and I am trying to get the intersection polygons between them.

I understand that the intersect function from the raster package and gIntersection from the rgeos package can do this job (with a few differences) but they cannot handle all my polygons at once (about 50.000 polygons/entity).

For this reason, I have to split my calculation within a loop, saving the result for each step. The problem is: these functions keep filling my physical memory, and I cannot clean it. I tried using rm() and gc(), but it does not change a thing. The memory issue crashes my R session, and I cannot do my calculation.

Is there a way to free the RAM during simulation, within loops ? Or to avoid this memory issue ?

Here comes a reproducible example, for random polygons.

```
library(raster)
library(sp)
library(rgeos)

#Generating 50000 points (for smaller polygons) and 150000 (for larger polygons) in a square of side 100000
size=100000

Nb_points1=50000
Nb_points2=150000
start_point=matrix(c(sample(x = 1:size,size = Nb_points1,replace = T),sample(x = 1:size,size = Nb_points1,replace = T)),ncol=2)
start_point2=matrix(c(sample(x = 1:size,size = Nb_points2,replace = T),sample(x = 1:size,size = Nb_points2,replace = T)),ncol=2)

#Defining different sides length
radius=sample(x = 1:50,size = Nb_points1,replace = T)
radius2=sample(x = 1:150,size = Nb_points2,replace = T)

#Generating list of polygons coordinates
coords=list()
for(y in 1:Nb_points1){
  xmin=max(0,start_point[y,1]-radius[y])
  xmax=min(size,start_point[y,1]+radius[y])
  ymin=max(0,start_point[y,2]-radius[y])
  ymax=min(size,start_point[y,2]+radius[y])
  coords[[y]]=matrix(c(xmin,xmin,xmax,xmax,ymin,ymax,ymax,ymin),ncol=2)
}

coords2=list()
for(y in 1:Nb_points2){
  xmin=max(0,start_point2[y,1]-radius2[y])
  xmax=min(size,start_point2[y,1]+radius2[y])
  ymin=max(0,start_point2[y,2]-radius2[y])
  ymax=min(size,start_point2[y,2]+radius2[y])
  coords2[[y]]=matrix(c(xmin,xmin,xmax,xmax,ymin,ymax,ymax,ymin),ncol=2)
}

#Generating 75000 polygons
Poly=SpatialPolygons(Srl = lapply(1:Nb_points1,function(y) Polygons(srl = list(Polygon(coords=coords[y],hole = F)),ID = y)),proj4string = CRS('+init=epsg:2154'))
Poly2=SpatialPolygons(Srl = lapply(1:Nb_points2,function(y)Polygons(srl =  list(Polygon(coords=coords2[y],hole = F)),ID = y)),proj4string = CRS('+init=epsg:2154'))

#Union of overlapping polygons
aaa=gUnionCascaded(Poly)
bbb=gUnionCascaded(Poly2)

aaa=disaggregate(aaa)
bbb=disaggregate(bbb)

intersection=gIntersects(spgeom1 = aaa,bbb,byid = T,returnDense = F)

#Loop on the intersect function
pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = ceiling(length(aaa)/1000), style = 3)

for(j in 1:ceiling(length(aaa)/1000)){
  tmp_aaa=aaa[((j-1)*1000+1):(j*1000),]
  tmp_bbb=bbb[unique(unlist(intersection[((j-1)*1000+1):(j*1000)])),]
  List_inter=intersect(tmp_aaa,tmp_bbb)
  gc()
  gc()
  gc()
  setTxtProgressBar(pb, j)
}
```

Thank you !

Comment: To avoid memory issues you could switch to `gdalUtils`.

Comment: I don't know this package. Could you help me with it ? What function can help me ? I don't see anything about memory or intersection.

Comment: `gdalUtils` is a very good and useful package but it won't help here.  It's mostly to play with rasters.  You use the raster package, but not on rasters so I doubt it would help.

Comment: R isn't that efficient for big GIS stuff.  I often prefer using R as a base to call other software.  For that, `RSAGA` is my favorite follwed by `RQGIS` and than more complicated `RGRASS7`.  All need you to install the appropriate software (can be done one shot with OSGEO4W).  They should succeed at your task.  I'm kind of busy right now, if I have chance later on I'll post an example.

Answer (score 3):

You can consider using the `st_intersects` and `st_intersection` functions of package `sf`. For example:

```
aaa2 <- sf::st_as_sf(aaa)
bbb2 <- sf::st_as_sf(bbb)
intersections_mat <- sf::st_intersects(aaa2, bbb2)
intersections <- list()
for (int in seq_along(intersections_mat)){
  if (length(intersections_mat[[int]]) != 0){
    intersections[[int]] <- sf::st_intersection(aaa2[int,], 
    bbb2[intersections_mat[[int]],])
  }
}
```

will give you an `intersection_mat` of length equal to `aaa`, and containing , for each feature of `aaa`, the "indexes" of `bbb` elements with which it intersects ("empty" if no intersection found):

```
> intersections_mat
Sparse geometry binary predicate list of length 48503, where the predicate was `intersects'
first 10 elements:
 1: 562
 2: (empty)
 3: 571
 4: 731
 5: (empty)
 6: (empty)
 7: (empty)
 8: 589
 9: 715
 10: (empty)
```

, and an `intersection` list containing the list of intersecting polygons:

```
>head(intersections)
[[1]]
Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 0 fields
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 98873 ymin: 33 xmax: 98946 ymax: 98
epsg (SRID):    2154
proj4string:    +proj=lcc +lat_1=49 +lat_2=44 +lat_0=46.5 +lon_0=3 +x_0=700000 +y_0=6600000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
                        geometry
1 POLYGON ((98873 33, 98873 9...

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 0 fields
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 11792 ymin: 3 xmax: 11806 ymax: 17
epsg (SRID):    2154
proj4string:    +proj=lcc +lat_1=49 +lat_2=44 +lat_0=46.5 +lon_0=3 +x_0=700000 +y_0=6600000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
                        geometry
1 POLYGON ((11792 3, 11792 17...
```

(i.e., `intersections[[1]]` is the intersection between polygon 1 of `aaa` and polygon 571 of `bbb`)

HTH.

Comment: Thanks, this package works perfectly ! I actually used the `sf::intersection` function directly on the two large `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`.

In case the intersection includes different geometry types (e.g. points, lines and polygons), it is necessary to "split" `intersection_mat` by type. Use `sf::st_geometry_type` before passing them back to spatial objects as meant in the `sp` package with `as(   ,"Spatial")`.

Comment: Glad it helped. I was suggesting the "double passage" because I was not finding a simple way to understand from the output of st_intersection what were the "originators" of the different output polygons. However, I now noticed on the help that "The sfc geometry list-column returned carries an attribute idx, which is an n-by-2 matrix with every row the index of the corresponding entries of x and y, respectively".

Comment: The loop over `interscection_mat` is therefore useless (as you saw already), and a direct call to `st_intersection` suffices. I could amend the reply if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

The example works fine for me (8 GB RAM), after a few changes to the loop. See below. Tese changes are not related to memory use --- you were not storing the results.

```
List_inter <- list()

for(j in 1:ceiling(length(aaa)/1000)){
    begin <- (j-1) * 1000 + 1
    end <- min((j*1000), length(aaa))
    tmp_aaa <- aaa[begin:end,]
    tmp_bbb <- bbb[unique(unlist(intersection[begin:end])),]
    List_inter[[j]] <- intersect(tmp_aaa,tmp_bbb)
    cat(j, "\n"); flush.console()
}

x <- do.call(bind, List_inter)
```

Alternatively, you could write the intermediate results to disk, and deal with them later:

```
inters <- intersect(tmp_aaa,tmp_bbb)
saveRDS(inters, paste0(j, '.rds'))
```

Or

```
shapefile(inters, paste0(j, '.shp'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My RAM usage still increase with this new loop. I did not store results in my example, indeed.

Comment: RAM use should increase as you create new objects. You may try writing the intermediate results to disk, and come back to them later. I have added some code for taht.